# Create a multi-level 5x5x5 Labyrinth with only one solution

Tags: code-golf, maze, generation

The aim of this challenge is to create the shortest code (in characters) that successfully do the following:

**Specifications**:

- Must create a `5x5x5 labyrinth` with exactly `1 possible solution` (no more, no less)
- <del>The labyrinth must be created `randomly`</del> It must be able to generate every existing solution if left running for years
- The `start` and `finish` must be placed in `*opposite corners`
- The map `output` must in one of the following formats:

**Option output format 1** `strings, printed or alerted`:

```
xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx/
xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx/
xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx/
xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx/
xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx
```

**Option output format 2** `arrays`:

```
[[xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx],
[xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx],
[xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx],
[xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx],
[xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx]]
```

**Output Notes:**

- Use `0` for `empty` and `1` for `squares`
- Break lines are *NOT* necessary
- You decide what `index` is what, but just make sure to *explain* it well

---

*Here is an example of what I mean by opposite corners:

[image]

**Clarifications**:

- Can *NOT* move in `diagonal`
- Can *NOT* pass twice on the same path
- Having `inaccessible areas` is allowed
- You can `go up/down` more than one level in a row

**Tips:**

- Don't see them as walls, instead see them as a `5x5x5` stack of squares that some of them are missing and you can go through the missing ones

Comment: If something is unclear, just ask me :)

Comment: Your specification of "printing in an understandable way" is still very vague. A _slightly_ more strict rule wouldn't harm.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think I should specify an exact output format to remove all vagueness. But I can't picture any way of expressing multidimensional things, I need help plx before someone start working

Comment: You could just ask for each level of the maze to be printed consecutively as ASCII art, with, say, an empty line between levels.

Comment: However, there's one detail I'd like a clarification on: are walls placed _between_ squares, or does a wall fill a whole square?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen added "Don't see them as walls, instead see them as a 5x5 stack of squares that some of them are missing and you can go through the missing ones"

Comment: you say 5x5 (a 2D array) in a few places, yet the code samples and image suggest 5x5x5 (a 3D array). I assume the 3D array is what's meant?

Comment: @KaeVerens yes, sorry about that (updating)

Comment: how is it decided that the solution is a valid labyrinth? I mean, is it the number of offshoots that the right path has? is it something to do with the ratio of 1s to 0s?

Comment: When you say "The labyrinth must be created randomly", what limitations should we infer? I presume, for example, that you don't intend to allow, as a literal reading of the rules currently does, a program which chooses between two hard-coded outputs at random.

Comment: @ajax Why not accept output in {x,y,z} coordinates?

Comment: Please post a sample labyrinth.

Comment: @KaeVerens it will be very hard to test if a solution is valid indeed, I guess we will need to manually build some random generated mazes in 3d and start testing.

Comment: @DavidCarraher chosing is different than creating. I think the current definition is ok (but I will try to clarify that in the next update)

Comment: Since there are 8 corners, but the opposite corners (Start-End) are indistinguishable from (End-Start), there are 4 possible Start-Corners to consider. Or can we say, that we only consider one start corner, since the other solutions are symmetric?

Comment: Another question: `exactly 1 solution` prohibits circular ways. But what about dead ends that lead nowhere - they are allowed, aren't they?

Comment: @userunknown yes, there could be 1 solution with dead ends as long as they don't make a circuit to either the same way or the solution

Comment: just out of curiosity, how can a block be accessible if it's a wall. and if that's no problem why can't I just declare every block out of the main path a wall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## <strike>C++</strike> C, <strike>about 1000</strike> <strike>670</strike> <strike>643</strike> <strike>395</strike> <strike>297</strike> 248 chars

Sample output:

```
00111,10011,10111,00110,11000,
11001,01010,00100,11011,10101,
10111,10101,10001,01010,00101,
11001,11110,11100,11110,10101,
11100,10010,11001,10101,00000,
```

How it works: <strike>The program uses [Brownian Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) to generate solutions.</strike> The start point is set. Then, a random point is selected <strike>and repeatedly moved randomly</strike> until it touches one and only one point on the start branch. The point is then set, and if it also touches the end point, the program exits and the matrix displayed. Since no point can join two branches, there is only one path through the labyrinth. The program uses the rand function, <strike>and a command line integer argument as the seed,</strike> so with a sufficient rand function it should be possible to eventually generate all valid labyrinths (this algorithm will not create unconnected areas however, so it won't generate all *possible* labyrinths).

Brownian motion was dropped since it turned out to be unneeded and it's removal simplifies the code significantly. I do think it made nicer labyrinths though. Likewise, the seed argument was dropped, since requiring a stateless random number generator makes more sense to me than a 128-bit seed.

It is possible for the program to get stuck in an infinite loop, since it is possible for situations where any point added to the branches would create multiple paths. This is fixable, but I think that it is rare enough to not be a concern for code golf.

```
#define M m[*p+1][p[1]][p[2]]
#define F(a,b)for(p[a]=5;p[a]--;putchar(b))
#define f for(i=3;i--;p[i]
p[]={4,4,4},h[3],m[7][6][6]={1};
main(i){
    for(M=2;h[1]^1||(M=1)^h[2];){
        f=rand()%5)
            h[i]=0;
        f++)
            p[i]++,
            h[M]++,
            p[i]-=2,
            h[M]++;
    }
    F(0,10)
        F(1,44)
            F(2,48+!M);
}
```

I've added newlines and indentation to the displayed code for readability.

Comment: I think you win this one ;-) there's no way I could shrink mine that far

Comment: I really enjoyed the competition :-) I'm a bit surprised we're still the only answers, I expected a golf scripter or similar would have beaten us both by now.

Comment: Somehow, a simple path, with no forks or decision nodes, doesn't seem to qualify as a true labyrinth. Try adding some blind alleys.

Comment: @David Carraher
The algorithm does generate dead ends and branching paths as shown in the sample. Not allowing a new point to connect two already existing branches simply prevents multiple solutions or cycles in the labyrinth.

Comment: @Sir_Lagsalot Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 5):

#### JavaScript, <strike>874</strike> <strike>816</strike> <strike>788</strike> <strike>686</strike> <strike>682</strike> <strike>668</strike> 637 characters

sample output:

```
00000,10111,10111,01010,11000
01011,01000,01010,01111,00011
00100,11010,00111,10111,11010
01111,10001,01110,01010,01000
00000,11110,00001,10101,10110
```

this one works by starting from point [0,0,0] and randomly adding attaching one more 0 next to an 0 wherever allowed (allowed==the new 0 is not next to any other 0s except the originator) until there are no more possible additions.

if any new 0 is next to the exit point (x*y*z == 48) then we open up the exit.

golfed

```
b=[]
I=Math.random
for(i=5;i--;)for(j=5,b[i]=[];j--;)b[i][j]=[1,1,1,1,1]
b[0][0][0]=0
k=[[0,0,0]]
function q(x,y,z){J=b[x]
if(x<0||y<0||z<0||x>4||y>4||z>4||!J[y][z])return 
n=6-!x||b[x-1][y][z]
n-=!y||J[y-1][z]
n-=!z||J[y][z-1]
n-=x==4||b[x+1][y][z]
n-=y==4||J[y+1][z]
n-=z==4||J[y][z+1]
n==1&&v.push([x,y,z])}while(I){F=k.length
B=k[C=0|I(v=[])*F]
x=B[0]
q(x-1,y=B[1],z=B[2])
q(x,y-1,z)
q(x,y,z-1)
q(x+1,y,z)
q(x,y+1,z)
q(x,y,z+1)
if(D=v.length){k.push(A=v[0|I()*D])
b[A[0]][A[1]][A[2]]=0
if(A[0]*A[1]*A[2]==48)b[4][4][4]=I=0}else{for(E=[];F--;)F^C&&E.push(k[F])
k=E}}for(i=25;i--;)b[H=0|i/5][i%5]=b[H][i%5].join('')
alert(b.join("\n"))
```

original

```
window.map=[];
for (i=0;i<5;++i) {
  map[i]=[];
  for (j=0;j<5;++j) {
    map[i][j]=[1,1,1,1,1];
  } 
} 
points=[[0,0,0]];
map[0][0][0]=0;
function spaces(x,y,z) {
  var n=6;
  if (x<0 || y<0 || z<0) return 0;
  if (x>4 || y>4 || z>4) return 0;
  if (!map[x][y][z]) return 0;
  if (!x || map[x-1][y][z]) n--;
  if (!y || map[x][y-1][z]) n--;
  if (!z || map[x][y][z-1]) n--;
  if (x==4 || map[x+1][y][z]) n--;
  if (y==4 || map[x][y+1][z]) n--;
  if (z==4 || map[x][y][z+1]) n--;
  return n;
} 
do {
  var index=Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length);
  point=points[index];
  v=[];
  x=point[0];
  y=point[1];
  z=point[2];
  spaces(x-1,y,z)==1 && v.push([x-1,y,z]);
  spaces(x,y-1,z)==1 && v.push([x,y-1,z]);
  spaces(x,y,z-1)==1 && v.push([x,y,z-1]);
  spaces(x+1,y,z)==1 && v.push([x+1,y,z]);
  spaces(x,y+1,z)==1 && v.push([x,y+1,z]);
  spaces(x,y,z+1)==1 && v.push([x,y,z+1]);
  if (v.length) {
    var point=v[Math.floor(Math.random()*v.length)];
    points.push(point);
    map[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]]=0;
    if (point[0]*point[1]*point[2]==48) {
      map[4][4][4]=0;
    } 
  } 
  else {
    var np=[];
    for (var i=0;i<points.length;++i) {
      i!=index && np.push(points[i]); 
    } 
    points=np;
  } 
} while(points.length);
for (i=0;i<5;++i) {
  for (j=0;j<5;++j) {
    map[i][j]=map[i][j].join('');
  } 
  map[i]=map[i].join();
} 
alert(map.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 4):

**Mathematica: True Labyrinth (827 chars)**

Originally, I produced a path from {1,1,1} to {5,5,5} but because there were no possible wrong turns to be made, I introduced forks or "decision points" (vertices of degree >2) where one would need to decide which way to go. The result is a true maze or labyrinth.

The "blind alleys" were far more challenging to solve than finding a simple, direct path. The most challenging thing was to eliminate cycles within the path while allowing cycles off the solution path.

The following two lines of code are only used for rendering the drawn graphs, so the code does not count, as it is not employed in the solution.

```
o = Sequence[VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
    ImageSize -> 600];

o2 = Sequence[ImagePadding -> 10, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", ImageSize -> 600];
```

**Code used:**

```
e[c_] := Cases[EdgeList[GridGraph[ConstantArray[5, 3]]], j_ \[UndirectedEdge] k_ /; (MemberQ[c, j] && MemberQ[c, k])]

m[] :=
Module[{d = 5, v = {1, 125}},
   While[\[Not] MatchQ[FindShortestPath[Graph[e[v]], 1, 125], {1, __, 125}],

v = Join[v, RandomSample[Complement[Range[125], v], 1]]];
   Graph[e[Select[ConnectedComponents[Graph[e[v]]], MemberQ[#, 1] &][[1]]]]]

w[gr_, p_] := EdgeDelete[gr, EdgeList[PathGraph[p]]]

y[p_, u_] := Select[Intersection[#, p] & /@ ConnectedComponents[u], Length[#] > 1 &]

g = HighlightGraph[lab = m[],  PathGraph[s = FindShortestPath[lab, 1, 125]],o]
u = w[g, s]
q = y[s, u]

While[y[s, u] != {}, u =  EdgeDelete[u, Take[FindShortestPath[u,  q[[1, r = RandomInteger[Length@q[[1]] - 2] + 1]], 
  q[[1, r + 1]]], 2] /. {{a_, b_} :> a \[UndirectedEdge] b}];

q = y[s, u]]

g = EdgeAdd[u, EdgeList@PathGraph[s]];

Partition[StringJoin /@ Partition[ReplacePart[Table["x", {125}], 
Transpose[{VertexList[g], Table["o", {Length[VertexList@g]}]}]/. {{a_, b_} :>  a -> b}], {5}], 5]
```

**Sample output**

{{"oxooo", "xxooo", "xoxxo", "xoxxo", "xxoox"}, 
 {"ooxoo", "xoooo", "ooxox", "oooxx", "xooxx"}, 
 {"oooxx", "ooxxo", "ooxox", "xoxoo", "xxxoo"}, 
 {"oxxxx", "oooox", "xooox", "xoxxx", "oooxx"}, 
 {"xxxxx", "ooxox", "oooox", "xoxoo", "oooxo"}}

**Under the hood**

The picture below shows the labyrinth or maze that corresponds to the solution `({{"ooxoo",...}}` displayed above:

[image: solution1]

Here is the same labyrinth inserted in a 5x5x5 `GridGraph`. The numbered vertices are nodes on the shortest path out of the labyrinth. Note the forks or decision points at 34, 64, and 114.
I'll include the code used for rendering the graph even though it is not part of the solution:

```
HighlightGraph[gg = GridGraph[ConstantArray[5, 3]], g,  
 GraphHighlightStyle ->"DehighlightFade", 
 VertexLabels -> Rule @@@ Transpose[{s, s}] ]
```

[image: solution2]

And this graph shows only the solution to the labyrinth:

```
HighlightGraph[gg = GridGraph[ConstantArray[5, 3]], 
   Join[s, e[s]], GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightFade", VertexLabels -> Rule @@@    Transpose[{s, s}] ]
```

[image: solution3]

Finally, some definitions that may help reading the code:

[image: definitions]

---

**Original solution (432 char, Produced a path but not a true maze or labyrinth)**

Imagine a 5x5x5 large solid cube made up of distinct unit cubes. The following begins without unit cubes at {1,1,1} and {5,5,5}, since we know they must be part of the solution. Then it removes random cubes until there is an unimpeded path from {1,1,1} to {5,5,5}.

The "labyrinth" is the shortest path (if more than one is possible) given the unit cubes that have been removed.

```
d=5
v={1,d^3}
edges[g_,c_]:=Cases[g,j_\[UndirectedEdge] k_/;(MemberQ[c,j]&&MemberQ[c,k])]

g:=Graph[v,edges[EdgeList[GridGraph[ConstantArray[d,d]]],v]];

While[\[Not]FindShortestPath[g,1,d^3]!={},
    v=Join[v,RandomSample[Complement[Range[d^3],v],1]]]

Partition[Partition[ReplacePart[
   Table["x",{d^3}],Transpose[{FindShortestPath[g,1,d^3],Table["o",{Length[s]}]}]
      /.{{a_,b_}:>  a->b}],{d}]/.{a_,b_,c_,d_,e_}:>  StringJoin[a,b,c,d,e],5]
```

Example:

```
{{"ooxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx"}, 
 {"xoxxx", "xoooo", "xxxxo", "xxxxo", "xxxxo"}, 
 {"xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxo"}, 
 {"xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxo"}, 
 {"xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxo"}}
```

Technically this is not yet a true labyrinth, since there are no wrong turns that one can make. But I thought it interesting as a start since it relies on graph theory.

The routine actually makes a labyrinth but I plugged up all empty locations that could give rise to cycles.  If I find a way to remove cycles I will include that code here.

Comment: Nice update, I like that your updated solution allows cycles on non-solution paths, it makes for a more confusing labyrinth.

Comment: Thanks. I would still like to have the solution path itself be more likely to veer away from the final node from time to time. This is presently discouraged (but not fully prevented) by `FindShortestPath`.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with matlab, but could you do something like FindShortestPath, add a bias against each node in the shortest path, and then run FindShortestPath again taking into account the bias so that it will avoid nodes in the shortest solution? This could be done iteratively too. I'd be interested in seeing what type of path that would produce.

Comment: @Sir_Lagsalot I posted this as a question for the Mathematica SE group here (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/finding-a-not-shortest-path-between-two-vertices  )